# Javax.naming.* port to Android?

Tags: java, android, email, ldap, exchange-server

Does anyone know of a LDAP package (or `javax.naming.*`) port to Android?  I'm looking to implement a full contact search based on input from the user.

I have it working with the Java version of the app, but as I port it over, Android doesn't support `javax.naming.*`. If there isn't a way to port that API, is there a way to include it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java works on Android as well as Java SE/EE.  It even includes the code for a simple Android app that can be used to perform searches in an LDAP directory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing the things a bit. LDAP servers are not available on mobile. To search contact you should probably look at [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html).

Comment: I'm really tired and will have to check that out tomorrow in the AM... Do you know offhand if that will work for exchange servers as well?

I am mixing the LDAP and the exchange contacts, but the exchange contacts need to be loaded through the GAL/active directory, not a local DB.